# Looking for a short story about a 'transhuman' clandestine operative

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for a short story about a seemingly superhuman person on a clandestine mission. We find out that he isn’t a superhuman but is well-trained and conditioned to perform the mission; he can see in the dark, can read minds (but this is his ability to hear sub-vocalized thoughts) along with great speed and agility. At the end of the story we are told that he will spend a long time recuperating from the mission as he is burnt out physically and mentally. Read in the 80’s in a short story collection. That’s all I remember.

Comment: This reminds me of the *[Blackcollar](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/Blackcollar)* books.

Comment: I don't think it's that one but that series does look good. Thanks for replying.

Comment: So, he does not have the supernatural ability to read thoughts (electrical impulses). Just the supernatural ability to hear and interpret the miniscule laryngeal movements that correspond to auditory and linguistic processing and recall, which produce sounds that are impossibly quiet and drowned in body noise? Does he also have the supernatural ability to cause people to subvocalize when engaged in nonverbal thought?

Comment: Yes, it's along the lines you mention but he doesn't have the ability to cause people to subvocalize. Not supernatural powers but enhanced human abilities..

Comment: @Roysto - Tomayto, tomahto.

Comment: This is a Poul Anderson story, part of his UN-Man series.

Comment: @NomadMaker Maybe "The Sensitive Man"

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez Thank you, that's it.

Comment: @NomadMaker You should write up an answer - I think it fits very well

Comment: @Roysto - Tomayto, tomahto. – Adamant  15 hours ago
Uhh?

Comment: Thanks everybody. Looks like The Sensitive Man is the one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to NomadMaker identifying the author as Poul Anderson, I believe that a strong candidate for an answer is the novella "[The Sensitive Man](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58315)", first published in 1954 in *Fantastic Universe*.

The story takes place in the far-future year of 2009(!), and is set in Poul's "[Psychotechnic League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Psychotechnic_League)" future history. A summary at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sensitive_Man) describes the plot well:

> Michael Tighe of the Psychotechnic Institute has been kidnapped by
> Thomas Bancroft, a politician with ties to an authoritarian movement
> called the Actionists. Tighe's adopted son, Simon Delgatty, sets out
> to find him, but is himself captured by Bancroft and taken to his base
> on an island off the coast of Mexico. In the course of raising
> Delgatty, Tighe has trained him to exert conscious control over what
> are normally subconscious and autonomic brain functions. This allows
> Delgatty to speed up or slow down his metabolism at will, and also
> allows him to tell what other people are thinking by listening to them
> subvocalize their thoughts.

As the question noted, the protagonist, Delgatty,was trained to take advantage of "the relationship between the conscious, subconscious and involuntary minds" to have a perfect memory, have superhuman physical abilities, and to apparently read people's minds. In fact, however this is due to:

> Most people sub-vocalize their surface thoughts. With a little
> practice a person who can hear those vibrations can learn to interpret
> them.

His abilities take a toll on his body though.

> "There are sound biological reasons why man's mind is so divided and
> plenty of penalties attached to a case like mine. It'll take me a
> couple of months to get back in shape after this bout. I'm due for a
> good old-fashioned nervous breakdown and while it won't last long it
> won't be much fun while it does last."

The complete story is available at [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/31501/31501-h/31501-h.htm).

Comment: This it, thanks.